# Universal Links issue on iOS 14

Tags: ios, ios14, ios-universal-links

I have an app supporting UniversalLink. User who click the supported links in the website, will be navigated to the features in the application.
But It is not working with iOS 14 beta 4. Instead of opening of the app, it diverted to webpage instread.

**UniversalLink was working fine when I have selected development or hdhok provisioning profiles. But when I upload it to TestFlight it’s not working.**

After research, as I can see from the document here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains

For iOS 14 support I Added a query string to my associated domains entitlement as follows (for Development mode) :

```
   <service>:<fully qualified domain>?mode= developer
```

I have use a private web server that’s unreachable from the public internet. But if I select distribution certificates then which alternate mode I have to set to bypass the CDN and connect directly to my private domain?

Created my apple-app-site-association file. Here is my file :

```
{
"applinks": {
    "details": [
    {
    "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ],
    "components": [
    
    {
    "/": "/coupleinvite/*",
    "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /coupleinvite/"
    },
    {
    "/": "/menu/groupvideocall/*",
    "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /menu/groupvideocall/"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
}
}
```

add domain to the entitlement

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
    <string>applinks:example .com</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I'm trying to setup iOS14 in developer mode, but I'm getting no success. The phone is not making any calls to check the JSON file? did it work for you right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10098) on this topic (near the end).  Testflight will not work with the developer mode switch.  Only works as you described.

> There are two alternate modes in macOS Big Sur and iOS 14, and they're distinguished by when you would use them.
>
> The first alternate mode is called "developer mode," and it's designed for use when you're building and testing your app before you deploy it to TestFlight or end users.
>
> The second alternate mode is called "managed mode" and is for use when your app is installed using an MDM profile. We'll be focusing today on developer mode.

> Apps signed for distribution on the App Store or TestFlight or Mac apps that have been signed and notarized cannot be used with this alternate mode.

Key point above is "before you deploy it to Testflight".

Comment: What I should do to make Universal-link Working for the TestFlight?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure there is a method with TestFlight builds that will support universal links if your environment is private like you mention. You'd have to test that feature w/Xcode builds. You can definitely upload debug builds accessing private environments to TestFlight but universal links and app review won't work for those builds.